# Angular App on GitHub Pages show "Your site is ready to be published" but status never updates

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I'm trying to use GitHub pages to deploy my Angular App.

**Issue**: GitHub Pages show "Your site is ready to be published" but status never updates (despite refreshing, retrying, etc.).

**GitHub Repo**: https://github.com/KConlonCoder/rustic-restaurant-app

**GitHub Page**: https://kconloncoder.github.io/rustic-restaurant-app

**Steps taken**:

1. Navigated to the Angular app folder: rustic-app.
2. Checked out a git branch gh-pages. Set up the GitHub remote origin for my existing repository.
3. Build code: `ng build --output-path docs --base-href /rustic-app/`
4. Pushed everything to GitHub.
5. Under Settings > Pages, updated the branch to gh-pages and selected /docs as the folder.

*(Note: https://www.githubstatus.com says everything's working fine.)*

**Issue:**

At this point, GitHub Pages show "Your site is ready to be published" but that status never updates (despite refreshing, retrying, etc.). Could this be due to the folder structure on GitHub? All of the files and folders for the app are under a root folder "rustic-app". Is GitHub pages unable to find the docs folder for this reason?

I pushed the files while in the rustic-app, so I'm not sure why it's also pushing the folder I'm in. See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxA9u.jpg).

**6/18/22 UPDATE**: I checked under GitHub Actions and the build job is running into this error, but I don't have any references to css/style.scss anywhere that I can see.

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

Comment: Side note: Git never pushes *files*. Git pushes *commits*. A commit then contains files (so it's almost the same thing), but the thing to keep in mind here is that it's all-or-nothing: a commit has a *full snapshot of every file*. Checking out some particular commit means that you see *those files* and not other files. Moreover, a commit never holds *folders*, only *files* - the files have slashes in their names and the system will create folders as needed to match.

Comment: The folder-display thing is just GitHub being GitHub: they don't display the entire contents of a commit all at once, forcing you to click on a folder to see what's within it. The commit still holds all the files, though. If they're not supposed to be in a sub-folder, that could be a problem. I'm not familiar with this particular Angular etc stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t think the files are supposed to be inside that main folder, but I’m not sure.